# (Maybe) Stop start foreach loop to fix Bootstrap structure

Tags: php, html, foreach, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get and display data using a foreach loop, but running across issues on getting the aesthetics right with Bootstrap 4.

**Here is a mockup of the layout I'm trying to achieve**:

[image]

**Here is my current markup**:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-row">

    <?php 
      $i = 0;
      foreach( $col as $item ){
        $itle=$item->childNodes[1]->nodeValue;
        if(++$i > 4) break;
    ?>
    
    <?php if ($i == 1) { ?>
    <div class="large d-flex flex-column">
      <span class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    
    <!-- resourceGrid is still in the forloop, so it's rendered three times 
    
    Can I do the following here:
    
    - stop the forloop here
    
    <div class="resourceGrid d-flex flex-column"> so that it's only printed once
    
    - resume the forloop
    -->
    
    <?php if ($i > 1) { ?>
    <div class="resourceGrid d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
      <?php } ?>


    <?php } ?> <!-- end for each -->
  </div>
</div>
```

However, all my content just spits out in a row (due to `flex-row`). I think the correct way to approach this would be to stop the for loop before `<div class="small">` but then its content will be undefined.

I want the `small` content to be in a column as the image depicts, but cannot nest a column within another column.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: A snippet error childNodes[1]->nodeValue; if(++$i > 4) break; ?>
1) { ?>

Comment: So you only want to output a maximum of four items here anyway? This does not need to continue in the same fashion, even if there are more items? Do you always have at least four items, or can it be less (and what would it be supposed to look like in that case?)

Comment: @04FS Yes, the maximum will always be four items. Essentially what I want is the `large` card to be `col-6` and the `small` card to be `col-4` but in a column layout. I have the `small` card div in a container called `resourceGrid`, which is `flex-column`. However, since I'm still looping through to get its content, the `resourceGrid` is getting printed three times.

Comment: I would simply not try to do this all in one foreach loop to begin with. Output the first item on its own first, then loop over the rest, to output items #2 to #4 in a loop inside a grouping parent element …